# Click Listeners on the Horizontal RecyclerView in a Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android

I will try to explain my problem in brief here. Please refer to the github link for my project if my explanation here not enough. [Github link](https://github.com/Sourabhlpu/NewsFeedV1/tree/firebase/app)

I have a horizontal recycler view inside a vertical recycler view. I've on click listeners for the vertical items and that just works fine.

I want to also have an onClickListener for the horizontally scrolling list. But the app crashes when I implement the same for it.

I've implemented the click listener using an interface in the adapter and implementing the interface in the fragment/activity.

I am initializing the horizontal recycler view and the adapter for it inside the main adapter and not in the  activity code.

I am getting the following error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

[image: Error Image]

Comment: In which adapter/viewholder does the crash occur? It seems like your passing a null context in the adapter. You should consider passing an interface trough the constructor(s) of the both the adapters and implementing the actual click event in your fragment/activity.

Comment: @TimKranen I've attached the screenshot of the error in the question. SectionRVAdapter in the screenshot is the adapter for the horizontal recycler view

Comment: @TimKranen That is the approach I am using. That approach works fine for the vertical recycler view but not for Horizontal recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking trough your code I found that the problem lies in the `RVAdapter` on like no. 380:

```
holder.horizontalAdapter = new SectionRVAdapter(holder.context,holder.sections, new MainActivityFragment());
```

Right here you pass the fragment as a click listener, but instead of passing the fragment instance that you already have you create a new fragment instance. This fragment will get called when the user clicks but it doesn't have a context since it hasn't been attached (there hasn't been any fragment transaction).

What you should do instead is pass the fragment you already have. Right now you have a `ListItemOnClickHandler` in your RVAdapter, but it should be an interface that can handle both clicks. What I would do is the following;

- Create an interface that has two methods, a regular list click (i.e. `onListItemClicked()`) and a method to handle horizontal clicks (i.e. `onHorizontalItemClicked()`)
- Make sure the fragment implements this interface (let's call it, `ClickInterface`)
- Pass `ClickInterface` in the constructor of `RVAdapter`, save it in a field and when initalizing the SubsectionRVAdapter pass the SAME click listener (the same instance)

That way you can pass around your fragment without having to worry about the context not being present. You can then call the appropriate methods in the ViewHolders of each respective adapter.

Hope thats gonna work!

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what came to my mind while I was just traveling in the car and thinking about the problem. I've not yet applied the solution but I am sure that will solve the problem. This is exactly where I thought the problem lies and thought about the same solution. Thank you for taking time and actually going through the code.

Comment: @SourabhPal No problem :) If you like the answer please accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Since you've taken a look at my project, can you please suggest me a few things?(Not sure if I should a new question for this).